# JavaScript - return function value outside of another function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, twilio, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to get the returned response from the code below.
The below is a cloud function (Parse Server) which currently not returning anything, the only returned value is inside `.then(verification => {})`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendVerificationCode", async (request) => {
    await client.verify.services('VAc357322eb2d70fd893237ba44d42333')
        .verifications
        .create({
            to: request.params.phoneNumber,
            channel: 'sms',
        }).then(verification => {
            //The value here is readable
            return verification;
        }, error => {
            return error;
        });

    // Can I return `verification` value here too?
});
```

The question is, can I return `verification` value below `await` ?

P.S. I use the client side to get the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendVerificationCode", async (request) => {
    return await client.verify.services('VAc357322eb2d70fd893237ba44d42333')
        .verifications
        .create({
            to: request.params.phoneNumber,
            channel: 'sms',
        });
});
```

This will return verification where you ask for it but I can not see where this value should be returned to since the whole function is passed as a callback.

Comment: The value is returned on the client-side. Concerning your suggestion, it seems that it's not working as it returned `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: This answer should work. You probably have some problem in the client side as well. Is this error message popping up in the client side, right? Can you share the code that you are using to call this cloud code function?